# Sikuli integration with Selenium Webdriver info

Tags: selenium-webdriver, sikuli

I have added all the required jars in the build path, but I get this error when the execution reaches Sikuli APIs

```
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: checkLibsDir: libs dir is not on system path: C:\Users\general\Desktop\Sikuli\libs
[action] ResourceLoaderBasic: checkLibsDir: Please wait! Trying to add it to user's path
[info] runcmd: reg QUERY HKCU 
[info] runcmd: reg QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v PATH 
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: checkLibsDir: Logout and Login again! (Since libs folder is in user's path, but not activated)
[error] Terminating SikuliX after a fatal error!
```

Sorry, but it makes no sense to continue!
If you do not have any idea about the error cause or solution, run again
with a Debug level of 3. You might paste the output to the Q&A board.

Here is my code

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.sikuli.script.App;
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;

public class Sikuli_test3 {

@Test
public void functionName() throws FindFailed {

// Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 


// And now use this to visit Google 
driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");

//WebElement element = driver.findElement( By.id("gbqfq"));
//element.sendKeys("Hello");
//element.click();

//Create and initialize an instance of Screen object    
Screen screen = new Screen();

//Add image path   
Pattern image = new Pattern("C:\\sikuli_images\\iam_feeling_lucky.png");

//Wait 10ms for image  
screen.wait(image, 10);

//Click on the image
screen.click(image);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if User defined environment variables `%SIKULI_HOME%` is present in your system and is added to the `PATH` environment variable. If present, restart your system. This should work.

http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html

Let me know if this helps you.